# Creating a TFS Custom Build Process (TFS2013)

Tags: tfs, build, build-process, tfsbuild

My group is trying to move over to TFS from our custom-coded build process. Unfortunately, I'm  new to TFS build processes and as I dig deeper into creating custom build processes, the more I realize I don't know how to do some basic things. Can anyone help me with the following?

Due to our need to often patch older releases for various customers unable/unwilling to move to newer releases, we're using a branch-for-release model, with programmers committing to the trunk, and a branch created whenever we need to release. That way we can patch an older release should there be any problems.

So I need to do the following:

On queuing a build, input parameters so that we can define versioning, branch name, and information to include.

Programatically branch the trunk and build from that branch.

Any thoughts on the matter? I'm beginning to think the branch-on-release strategy doesnt work well with TFS, so if anyone has a good idea on how to set up the process such that we can make regular releases, but still patch older releases, I'm all ears.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but I see two scenarios:

1. You build from trunk, and branch for safekeeping from each release.  In which case I see no problems.
2. You branch for each release and build from that branch.  In which case I would suggest creating a new build definition for each branch (but reusing the custom build process template).

Comment: Is there a way I can create a build process that automatically branches the code for me, or do I have to do that manually? It would also be nice if I could have the same build process check in files on that branch, to set the compiled version reporting of the executable (Ie write and commit a quick version.h file before building my code)

The reason I would want queue-time parameters would be to define the branch name of whatever branch is automatically created, and to define what info is written into version.h

Comment: Sure you can do all that but you'll have to customize the build template (workflow) to achieve it.  If you google for the ALM Ranger Build Guidance it describes in detail how to customize a build template.